# Python function to accept numpy ndarray or sequence as arguments

Tags: python, function, numpy, arguments

I have seen some python functions that work generally receiving a (n,2) shaped numpy ndarray as argument, but can also "automagically" receive (2,n) or even len(2) sequences (tuple or list).

How is it pythonically achieved? Is there a unified good practice to check and treat these cases (example, functions in numpy and scipy module), or each developer implements which he thinks best?

I'd just like to avoid chains of (possibly nested) chains of ifs/elifs, in case there is a well known better way.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [numpy.asarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) function to convert any sequence-like input to an array:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.asarray([1,2,3])
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> numpy.asarray(numpy.array([2,3]))
array([2, 3])
>>> numpy.asarray(1)
array(1)
>>> numpy.asarray((2,3))
array([2, 3])
>>> numpy.asarray({1:3,2:4})
array({1: 3, 2: 4}, dtype=object)
```

It's important to note that as the documentation says *No copy is performed if the input is already an ndarray*. This is really nice since you can pass an existing array in and it just returns the same array.

Once you convert it to a numpy array, just check the length if that's a requirement. Something like:

```
>>> def f(x):
...    x = numpy.asarray(x)
...    if len(x) != 2:
...       raise Exception("invalid argument")
... 
>>> f([1,2])
>>> f([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in f
Exception: invalid argument
```

**Update:**
Since you asked, here's a "magic" function that will except *args as an array also:

```
>>> def f(*args):
...    args = numpy.asarray(args[0]) if len(args) == 1 else numpy.asarray(args)
...    return args
... 
>>> f(7,3,5)
array([7, 3, 5])
>>> f([1,2,3])
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> f((2,3,4))
array([2, 3, 4])
>>> f(numpy.array([1,2,3]))
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Would there be a way for it to consider a LIST OF INDIVIDUAL ARGUMENTS (the one stored in *args) as an array, too? So I could call `function(x,y)`, `function([x,y])`, `function(numpy.array([[x],[y]]))`...?

Comment: sure, just make it ``def f(*args)`` and use ``numpy.asarray(args[0]) if len(args) == 1 else numpy.asarray(args)``

Comment: I agree this answer is probably the best approach if you don't really care that you aren't dealing ith the original value / instance.  But if say someone wanted to do an actual check, something like isinstance(arg, (Sequence, numpy.ndarray), or a magic function like is_array_like(arg) (hich I think numpy should supply, maybe they do). So it maybe doesn't actually answer the question.